# How to sparate multy month weeks into different weeks in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have this query

```
select date_trunc('week', date)::date "start,
(date_trunc('week', date) + '6 days')::date "end"
from generate_series(now()::date, now()::date + '3 month'::interval, '1 week'::interval) as date
```

This works fine for most part. But i need to improve it so that weeks taht start in 1 month and end in another gets separated into 2 different weeks.
Example week 2023-10-30  -  2023-11-05 woule be made into 2023-10-30  - 2023-10-31 and 2023-11-01 - 2023-11-05.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach another, dependent `generate_series()` to produce an additional row for the last week of the month, and use that to start before or after the end of the month: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Swow2v8I)

```sql
select case tick when 0 then week_start
                 when 1 then next_month_start 
                 end as "start",
       case tick when 0 then least(   end_of_week,end_of_month)
                 when 1 then greatest(end_of_week,end_of_month) 
                 end as "end"
from (
select tick,
       week_start::date                        AS week_start,
       (week_start +'6 days '::interval)::date AS end_of_week,
       (date_trunc('month', week_start) 
        +'1 month'::interval           )::date AS next_month_start,
       (date_trunc('month', week_start)
        +'1 month'::interval       
        -'1 day  '::interval           )::date AS end_of_month
from generate_series(date_trunc('week',now()), 
                     date_trunc('week',now()) + '3 month'::interval, 
                     '1 week'::interval) as g(week_start),
     generate_series(0,( date_trunc('month', week_start)
                         +'1 month'::interval
                         -week_start < '6 days'::interval )::int) as t(tick)
) subquery;
```

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-10-09 | 2023-10-15 |
| 2023-10-16 | 2023-10-22 |
| 2023-10-23 | 2023-10-29 |
| **2023-10-30** | **2023-10-31** |
| **2023-11-01** | **2023-11-05** |
| 2023-11-06 | 2023-11-12 |

Comment: This works for the most part. There seems to be a situation where it breaks tho. Right now im getting an issue where this year ends on 31. december that is a sunday. So it generates me a row start 2024-01-01  end 2023-12-31. I have been trying to fix it but nothing seems to work.

Comment: There was a missing `date_trunc()` that broke the ticker and made the whole thing work differently depending on what day it was run on. Which also explains why it seemed to work fine for me yesterday, but not today. I added a fix and a [test in the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2yf3g0jo) that shows it no longer generates any pairs where it claims a week starts later or on the same date it also ends.